# "User does not exist or is not unique" error when creating Team Project in Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, tfs

I have SharePoint 2010 and Team Foundation Server 2012 installed on the same system.

SharePoint site collection for TFS projects: `http://tfsserver/sites/TFS`

When I try to create a new team project in Visual Studio 2012, it fails with the following:

[image: screenshot of exception message]

Error TF218017 seems to pertain to permissions. The `sites/TFS` collection in SharePoint has my user account listed with full access. Going to the TFS security administration page, I am in the "Project Collection Administrators" group.

I have researched the "User does not exist or is not unique" issue, and all signs point to it being an issue with the fact that TFS does not work with Claims based authentication in SharePoint; however, the SharePoint application is configured with Windows (Classic) authentication.

Any idea what my problem could be?

Comment: Does the account that is used for the TFS service have enough permission in SharePoint? It might be that this account is used instead of the one of the user requesting a new TeamProject.

Comment: @MikeR checked and the service account did not have permissions, so I added that account in SharePoint and in the TFS Project Collection Administrators group. Still getting the same error. I have read that there are some cache folders I might should clear out.

Comment: @MikeR cleared caches, still no luck.

Comment: It should be C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\<version>.  Is your web application using Classic Mode Authentication or Claims? I read that this could be an issue too.  Maybe this thread helps you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65f6433d-f663-4a8d-aa4c-5371a1ca9ddd/tf218017-a-sharepoint-site-could-not-be-created-for-use-as-the-team-project-portal-tf30063

Comment: @MikeR Yeah, I mentioned that in my post. I thought that would be it, but we are using Classic auth.